# Setting up Boost library on MacOS with Clion

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

So this is where my boost library path (where all .hpp files are):

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.80.0/include/boost
```

How should I set this up in Clion to start using <boost/.*> as headers in cpp files?

This is how my CMakeList.txt looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(laboratorium_1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(BOOST_ROOT "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.80.0")

find_package(Boost 1.80.0)

set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.80.0/include")

find_package(Boost 1.80.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find boost!")
endif()


add_executable(laboratorium_1 main.cpp Faktura.cpp Faktura.h Produkt.cpp Produkt.h PozycjaFaktury.cpp PozycjaFaktury.h)
```

It does not work.

Comment: *'It does not work'* Could you please say what that means, what errors you see? There could easily be important clues in any error messages that you are seeing.

Comment: You are  not using boost with your `laboratorium_1` target at all.

Comment: `-- Found Boost: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.80.0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.80.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.80.0", minimum required is "1.80.0")  
-- Found Boost: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.80.0/lib/cmake/Boost-1.80.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.80.0", minimum required is "1.80.0") found components: system filesystem 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/admin/CLionProjects/laboratorium_1/cmake-build-debug` this it my view from Debug window of CMakeList.txt file @john

Answer (score 0):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(laboratorium_1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(BOOST_ROOT /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.80.0)
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.80.0/include)
set(BOOST_LIBRARY_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.80.0/lib)

find_package(Boost 1.80.0 COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

if(NOT Boost_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find boost!")
endif()


add_executable(laboratorium_1 main.cpp Faktura.cpp Faktura.h Produkt.cpp Produkt.h PozycjaFaktury.cpp PozycjaFaktury.h)
```

The last comment on this thread contains a solution which worked for me:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206607995-Does-CLion-support-boost-library-